# Non functional scrollbar with CSS overflow-y property

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm working on a chat system and I would like a functional scrollbar to appear to go to the top / beginning of the conversation.

I use `overflow-y` CSS propery. When its value is egal to `scroll`, the scrollbar appears but it is not functional.

The best mode would be `auto` for `overflow-y`.

I need some help to make it work please.

Full code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-fpx45).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the full code but there was no problem

`overflow-y : scroll` is ok

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mohamadreza Hedayati : it helps me to figure out that it actually works with Brave and Chromium browsers, but not with Firefox Developer Edition 77.0b6 (64 bits) neither with Firefox 76.0 (64 bits). And you also can see into the sandbox that the scrollbar is not working... Any idea of how to normalize this ? Thank you.